# Add lambda in stream to define if a list reversed or not

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following method:

```
    private List<Residence> getHighestPriceResidenceDistinct(List<Residence> residences, Sort.Direction direction, int numOfResidences) {
        return residences.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Residence::getResidenceId,
                            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice))
                    )
            )
            .values()
            .stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice).reversed())
            .limit(numOfResidences)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It returns `n` number of `Residence` objects - in a list. A `Residence` object has fields `price::BigDecimal`, and `id::String`. The above method, requests the `numOfResidences` unique, most expensive Residence objects, and -due to the addition of `reversed()` - lists them starting from the most expensive one. The getHighestPriceResidenceDistinct method also has the `Sort.Direction` parameter. I would like to add a `lambda expression`, that defines if the `reversed()` will be used based on the value of the direction parameter.

Comment: Why does it have to be a lambda expression? Just use the ternary operator: `.sorted(yourFlag? Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice).reversed(): Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice))`. By the way, when you use `.collect( Collectors.toMap(Residence::getResidenceId, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice)) ) )`, it will simplify the entire operation, as you don’t need the subsequent `.filter(Optional::isPresent) .map(Optional::get)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    private List<Residence> getHighestPriceResidenceDistinct(List<Residence> residences, Sort.Direction direction, int numOfResidences) {
    return residences.stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Residence::getResidenceId,
                        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice))
                )
        )
        .values()
        .stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .sorted(Sort.Direction == "asc"? Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice): Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice).reversed())
        .limit(numOfResidences)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Don’t compare strings using `==`. Since the OP talked about a parameter, it’s unlikely that `Sort.Direction` is its name. Rather, it seems to be the type of the parameter, perhaps an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering your question but there is another solution: sort+distinct.
If the highest priced residences are encountered by the distinct first, then the lower priced residence will not get passed the distinct, eg:

```
    residences.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Residence::getPrice).reversed())
            .distinct()
            .limit(numOfResidences)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It might be more straight forward and efficient since its not collecting to an intermediate result, however it does require the residence class to implement equals/hashCode based on the residenceId.